# Replace the content of a specific column with sed/awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Provided file:

```
$ cat CronConfig 
 `FILE SYSTEM`
`------------` 
 warningThreshold: 77 
 criticalThreshold: 99

`MEMORY`
`-------`
warningThreshold: 66
criticalThreshold: 88

`CPU`
`----`
intervalCount: 6
intervalSecs: 7
warningThreshold: 99
criticalThreshold: 88
```

I have a file `CronConfig` with the above contents. I want to replace the values of `warningThreshold` and `criticalThreshold` and want the below output:

Desired File:

```
`FILE SYSTEM`
`------------`
warningThreshold: 11 
criticalThreshold: 22

`MEMORY`
`-------`
warningThreshold: 66
criticalThreshold: 88

`CPU`
`----`
intervalCount: 6
intervalSecs: 7
warningThreshold: 99
criticalThreshold: 88
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your post to include information on what you already tried and where you ran in to problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    !NF { f = 0 }
    /FILE SYSTEM/ { f = 1 }
    f && /warningThreshold/ { $2 = 11 }
    f && /criticalThreshold/ { $2 = 22 }
1' file
 `FILE SYSTEM`
`------------`
warningThreshold: 11
criticalThreshold: 22

`MEMORY`
`-------`
warningThreshold: 66
criticalThreshold: 88

`CPU`
`----`
intervalCount: 6
intervalSecs: 7
warningThreshold: 99
criticalThreshold: 88
```

Comment: Hi, it's showing the desired o/p in the command prompt but how we can overwrite this on the same file. Like what ever value we are providing in the command it should get over written in the same file as per the command line o/p

Comment: With any UNIX command `cmd` to overwrite the input file is `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file`. So redirect the output to a temp file and then move that temp file to overwrite the original. GNU awk also has a `-i inplace` option do do exactly the same thing internally (and sed, ruby, and perl have `-i` for the same thing) but that's all just unnecessary syntactic sugar.

Comment: sed has this -i option but i don't think awk has the same option. I kept redirect of o/p to a temp file as my last option. But before that just trying to ensure, if we can modify the existing file without creating any tmp file.

Comment: I just specifically told you about the sed and awk options. GNU sed and BSD sed have 2 different variations of `-i` and GNU awk has the equivalent with `-i inplace`. All tools with this type of functionality use a temp file internally. You cannot modify the existing file without creating a temp file unless you read the whole input into a buffer in memory at once, modify it, close the input file, and then write the contents of the buffer back out to the original file but doing that is cumbersome and error-prone (e.g. a crashed process or memory issue would corrupt your original file) so YMMV.

Comment: Why do you care if a temp file is created or not?  Using a temp file is simple, robust and requires very, very little code.

Comment: $ cat CronConfig

`MEMORY`
`-------`
warningThreshold: 66
criticalThreshold: 88

`CPU`
`----`
intervalCount: 6
intervalSecs: 7
warningThreshold: 99
criticalThreshold: 88

I want to extract the values 88 from MEMORY and 6 from CPU. I am currently using the below to get these value, please suggest me if you have any better way
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="------------"} {print $4}' CronConfig | awk 'NF {print $2}'
88
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="------------"} {print $8}' CronConfig | awk 'NF {print $2}'
6

Comment: You can't post formatted text in a comment. If the example you provided in your question isn't adequate for us to test against then fix that example. If my answer doesn't do what you want then tell me in what way it is failing and I can probably help, don't throw out some completely different code with multiple awk scripts and pipes and tell me whatever that is doesn't work. But you said before it's showing the desired output so idk what the problem might be now or why you aren't just using it.

Comment: i was asking about a different scenario, anyways thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome, if you have a followup question then just post a new question on the forum as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `sed` by just stripping off anything after `warningThreshold:` or `criticalThreshold:` and replacing it with the desired number:

```
sed -e '/FILE SYSTEM/,/^$/ {' \
    -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*\(warningThreshold:\).*/\1 11/' \
    -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*\(criticalThreshold:\).*/\1 22/' \
    -e '}' CronConfig >CronConfig.new
```

or, equivalently,

```
sed '/FILE SYSTEM/,/^$/ {
        s/^[[:blank:]]*\(warningThreshold:\).*/\1 11/
        s/^[[:blank:]]*\(criticalThreshold:\).*/\1 22/
    }' CronConfig >CronConfig.new
```

The `\( ... \)` matches *and captures* the string within the parentheses, which makes it possible to use that string as `\1` in the replacement text.

The `^[[:blank:]]*` in the expressions allows for the line to have initial spaces or tabs. Any initial spaces or tabs on the line will be deleted.

The two substitutions are only carried out for the lines between the lines matching the string `FILE SYSTEMS` and he next empty line (i.e. in the first section of your file).

Comment: FILE SYSTEM
--------------------
warningThreshold: 88
criticalThreshold: 99

MEMORY
-------------
warningThreshold: 66
criticalThreshold: 88

CPU
------
intervalCount: 6
intervalSecs: 7
warningThreshold: 99
criticalThreshold: 88

Comment: Kindly check the above comment where i have given the exact content of the file.. There is no space before any of the parameters likes warning/critical threshold. And i have tried both the above methods but it didn't help in the way i want.

Comment: @Dibyaprakash Consider correcting the data in your question rather than posting it here in a comment. Formatting does not show very well in comments.

Comment: @kusalananda: OP's **edit** makes a `sed` based answer significantly more complex than your present answer... For awk, just adding an associative array occurrence counter to catch pattern occurrence's first line only:    `awk -F : 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } a[$1]++; ($1 ~ /^[[:blank:]]+warningThreshold/ && a[$1] == 1)   { $2 = " 11" } ...;1' ` etc.   For me curiously the `*` did not work in the regex. I had to resort to a `+`.

Comment: @Cbhihe It's _easier_ with `sed`. I actually deleted the `awk` variation because it would be too complex in comparison. I would avoid `+` here as it's clear from the user's comment above that there is no space at the start of the lines (even though the data in the question has a space first for the first section, which is why I leave the possibility for spaces in my solution).

Comment: @Dibyaprakash See updated answer.

Comment: wrt `I actually deleted the awk variation because it would be too complex in comparison` - it'd be very similar if you're happy with range expressions: `awk '/FILE SYSTEM/,/^$/ {
        if (/^[[:blank:]]*warningThreshold:/) $2 = 11;
        if (/^[[:blank:]]*criticalThreshold:/) $2 = 22
    }1' file`. The version I prefer using a flag instead of a range expression isn't much different either (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585238/133219).

Comment: @EdMorton So it is. I'll leave my answer as it currently is though. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried both the above sed commands but non of them are providing the desired o/p

Comment: @Dibyaprakash When I run the `sed` commands on the data that you have provided in the question, I get exactly the output that you say you expect. If you do not get that output, then it seems to me that the data shown in the question is not actually what you have.