# Extract content of a specific column with awk/sed

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Provided file:

```
$ cat CronConfig 
 `FILE SYSTEM`
`------------` 
 warningThreshold: 77 
 criticalThreshold: 99

`MEMORY`
`-------`
warningThreshold: 66
criticalThreshold: 88

`CPU`
`----`
intervalCount: 6
intervalSecs: 7
warningThreshold: 99
criticalThreshold: 88
```

I have a file `CronConfig` with the above contents. I want to use the values of `warningThreshold` from `MEMORY` and `criticalThreshold` from `CPU`and want the below output:

```
66
88
```

used command to get this values: (but not sure if am doing in a right way)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="------------"} {print $7}' CronConfig | awk 'NF {print $2}'

awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS="------------"} {print $15}' CronConfig | awk 'NF {print $2}'
```

Comment: Are the backticks in your data, or is that a leftover from formatting your question?

Comment: That script you're using in your question isn't the one I suggested and you accepted in [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585238/133219). Why are you now using a completely different approach with 2 calls to awk (one of which is gawk-specific) with a pipe between them instead of just making the very tiniest tweak to the previous script (`print $2` instead of `$2 = value`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` with multiline remplacement.

In short

```
$ sed -n '/`MEMORY`/,/^$/{s/^warningThreshold: \([0-9]*\)/\1/p};
          /`CPU`/,/^$/{s/^criticalThreshold: \([0-9]*\)/\1/p}' CronConfig
```

With more explanation:

`sed -n` dont print the entire file

To select the block on wich to search, use

```
/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/
```

where PATTERN1 and PATTERN2 are the block limits.
In your case, you can use `MEMORY` end `^$` for the first block, `CPU` and `^$` for the second one.

All you have to do then is replace the line containing warningThresholt or criticalThreshold with the following number. I'll do this with `s` sed command. The `p` ending the s command is used to echo the result.

Comment: I had to add additional line breaks after `{` and before `}` to make it work.

Comment: @nohillside Strange... There is no need of line break around a block in sed. In fact, there is no need for `{` nor `}` in this case since the block contains only one command. I put them more for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I get `sed: 1: "/`MEMORY`/,/^$/{s/^warn ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`, might be an issue with the `sed` version macOS supplies.

Comment: @nohillside You are right: I did not mention that I was using a gnu version

Comment: You need to change `$^` to `^$` in the second line.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Corrected, thanks

Comment: am currently using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 version and i have tried executing the above mention sed command but it prints nothing

Comment: it is not related to sed version but the exemple file you provide is inconsistent: the first line with warningThreshold begin with a space, the others not. My sed expression assume there is no space, like in your file. try with ‘...{s/warningThreshold‘ insteed of ‘...{s/^warningThreshold...‘ and do the same with criticalThreshold (delete ^).

Answer (score 0):

An AWK Solution for whichever value you want ( Multi-dimensional array not supported in my awk  , so used "|" in array index , its better for all awk versions also ) :

```
$ awk -F'`' '
  /[A-Z][A-Z]+/ {matchkey=$2}
  !/[-]+/ && !/[A-Z][A-Z]+/ && $0 { 
      split($0,values,":");
      for ( i in values ) gsub(" ","",values[i]);
      ar[matchkey"|"values[1]]=values[2]; 
      }
  END {print ar["MEMORY|warningThreshold"];print ar["CPU|criticalThreshold"]}
' CronConfig
66
88
```

In the END block ,  you can get whichever value you want :

For Ex:  `print ar["CPU|intervalCount"]` will print the value **"6"** from your input file.

Comment: perl -F'\n' -ln -00 -e '$,=$\;
  $h{ ($F[0] =~ /\`(.*)\`/)[0] } = { /^\s*(.*):\s*(.*)$/mg };
  print $h{MEMORY}{warningThreshold}, $h{CPU}{criticalThreshold} if eof;
' file

Comment: and its print nothing...

Comment: i have tried the above awk command and its print nothing

Comment: @Dibyaprakash : is the input file same as you mentioned above? Its working fine for me with the input file you have given...

Comment: @Dibyaprakash : Its well tested...without trying and just coping and pasting my last comment for name sake ...

Comment: what `[A-Z]` means is locale-specific and, for example, will include most lower-case letters in some locales. To select just upper case letters use the character class `[[:upper:]]` instead for portability between locales. idk if thats whats causing the OPs current problem or not of course but it is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed` and some other  tools:

```
$ sed -ne '
  /^`CPU`$/{
    :a;n;s/^criticalThreshold: //p;Ta
  }
  /^`MEMORY`$/{
    :b;n;s/^warningThreshold: //p;Tb
  }
' cinfigFile

$  perl -lane '
    print $F[1] if 
      (/^`MEMORY`$/ ... /^$/ and /^warningThreshold:/) 
               || 
      (/^`CPU`$/ ... /^$/ and /^criticalThreshold:/);
' configFile


$ awk -F'\n' -vRS= '

/^`MEMORY`\n/&&match($0,/\nwarningThreshold: [0-9]+/){
  print substr($0, RSTART+19, RLENGTH-19) }

 /^`CPU`\n/&&match($0,/\ncriticalThreshold: [0-9]+/){
  print substr($0, RSTART+20, RLENGTH-20) }
' configFile



$ perl -F'\n' -ln -00 -e '$,=$\;
     $h{ ($F[0] =~ /`(.*)`/)[0] } = { /^\s*(.*):\s*(.*)$/mg };
     print $h{MEMORY}{warningThreshold}, $h{CPU}{criticalThreshold} if eof;
' configFile
```